# How to pass on closures through multiple sctructs and functions

Tags: rust, closures

I have a hierarchy of structs where I need to call a method in the topmost struct from an Iterator::next implementation at the lowest level.

Current implementation is as follows:

[Functional abstract](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f5f51da2e8745a5a284262cdad535818):

```rust
pub struct TopLevel {
    answer: usize,
}

pub struct MidLevelIter<'mli> {
    count: usize,
    top_level: &'mli TopLevel,
}

pub struct MidLevel<'ml> {
    top_level: &'ml TopLevel,
}

pub struct LowestLevelIter<'lli> {
    count: usize,
    top_level: &'lli TopLevel,
}

impl TopLevel {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { answer: 42 }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> MidLevelIter<'_> {
        MidLevelIter {
            count: 1,
            top_level: self,
        }
    }

    fn calculate(&self, _: usize) -> &usize {
        &self.answer
    }
}

impl<'mli> Iterator for MidLevelIter<'mli> {
    type Item = MidLevel<'mli>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count < 2 {
            self.count = 2;
            Some(MidLevel {
                top_level: self.top_level,
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'lli> Iterator for LowestLevelIter<'lli> {
    type Item = &'lli usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count < 2 {
            self.count = 2;
            Some(self.top_level.calculate(self.count))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'ml> MidLevel<'ml> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> LowestLevelIter<'ml> {
        LowestLevelIter {
            count: 1,
            top_level: self.top_level,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let collector = TopLevel::new();

    for pc in collector.iter() {
        for sc in pc.iter() {
            println!("SC={}", sc);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but it kind of bothers me that I have to pass a reference to TopLevel through all these structs.

So, my idea was to pass only the required method as a closure. That way, the lower levels need not to know anything about the TopLevel construct.
[the following approach](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03f642f8603c7ee962e0d3c39bee9ae0), however, fails because of "cannot move out of `self.mapper` which is behind a mutable reference".

```rust
pub struct TopLevel {
    answer: usize,
}

pub struct MidLevelIter<'mli> {
    count: usize,
    mapper: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &'mli usize + 'mli>,
}

pub struct MidLevel<'ml> {
    mapper: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &'ml usize + 'ml>,
}

pub struct LowestLevelIter<'lli> {
    count: usize,
    mapper: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> &'lli usize + 'lli>,
}

impl TopLevel {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { answer: 42 }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> MidLevelIter<'_> {
        MidLevelIter {
            count: 1,
            mapper: Box::new(self.mapper()),
        }
    }

    fn calculate(&self, _: usize) -> &usize {
        &self.answer
    }

    fn mapper<'m>(&'m self) -> impl Fn(usize) -> &'m usize {
        move |secondary_index| self.calculate(secondary_index)
    }
}

impl<'mli> Iterator for MidLevelIter<'mli> {
    type Item = MidLevel<'mli>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count < 2 {
            self.count = 2;
            Some(MidLevel {
                mapper: self.mapper,
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'lli> Iterator for LowestLevelIter<'lli> {
    type Item = &'lli usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count < 2 {
            self.count = 2;
            Some((self.mapper)(self.count))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'ml> MidLevel<'ml> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> LowestLevelIter<'ml> {
        LowestLevelIter {
            count: 1,
            mapper: self.mapper,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let collector = TopLevel::new();

    for pc in collector.iter() {
        for sc in pc.iter() {
            println!("SC={}", sc);
        }
    }
}
```

Although I can understand what the compiler tells me there, I don't see how to circumvent it.

Comment: _"failed because of lifetime issues"_ it is a good habit to expand the exact error message that the compiler produced into the question itself. Also, as per the comment above, be sure that other people can easily reproduce the error.

Comment: You were absolutely right, so I rephrased my question and provided both a workable example, plus one that has compile errors

Comment: I think you may be interested by https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/08/03/GATs-stabilization-push.html

Answer (score 1):

Traits are the answer to my problem.

Basically, on the lowest level I just wanted to perform a transformation of some sort on the items of the iteration. Although closures looked suitable for that, Rust provides another feature to accomplish this: Traits.

On the lowest level, I want to convert a numerical index to a key reference. So make a trait for it:

```rust
trait IndexToKey {
    fn calculate(&self, _: usize) -> &usize;
}
```

This trait can now be passed on, e.g.:

```
pub struct MidLevelIter<'mli> {
    count: usize,
    mapper: &'mli dyn IndexToKey,
}
```

Originally, my TopLevel struct provided the logic, so let's implement the trait:

```
impl IndexToKey for TopLevel {
    fn calculate(&self, _ix: usize) -> &usize {
        &self.answer
    }
}
```

Now we can pass a reference to trait implementation down to the lowest level, which now simply performs the conversion:

```
impl<'lli> Iterator for LowestLevelIter<'lli> {
    type Item = &'lli usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count < 2 {
            self.count = 2;
            Some(self.mapper.calculate(self.count))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

No lifetime issues, no disclosure or dependency on implementation details of the TopLevel structs at the other levels.

[Implementation on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69183b38e6cf6ef399924276ee237fb8)

Comment: be aware than dynamic dispatch have generally a performance hit

Comment: @Stargateur: what would you suggest? I am aware that my approach require a virtual method table and thus a lookup during runtime.

Comment: I don't don't what suggest you cause I didn't understand why you wanted to write such feature. I probably would advice to keep your first version since I don't the problem with it